# Изменение локализации приложения вручную

Tags: java, android, локализация

Задача состоит в следующем: нужно предоставить пользователю возможность изменения языка интерфейса приложения (ru, en, uk, ну и по дефолту будет выбран en). Для реализации данного функционала было сделано:

1) были созданы папки ресурсов: values, values-uk, values-ru, values-en, куда занесены файлы string.xml с соотвествующим переводом контента.

2) с помощью Spinner выбирается и записывается в SharedPreferences индетефикаторы языка.

3) При запуске приложения в onCreate применяется локализация:

```
SharedPreferences preferences =  context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String lang = preferences.getString(Constants.LANGUAGE, "default");
  if (lang.equals("default")) {
     lang=context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getCountry();
  }
  Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
  Locale.setDefault(locale);
  Configuration config = new Configuration();
  config.locale = locale;
  Log.i("Lang change", "Locale=" + locale);
  context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
  context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Впринципи, почти все подтягивает и применяет, но не все. А именно, в некоторых местах (в некоторых диалогах и BaseAdapter-ах, NavigationDrawer) подтягивает локализацию именно языка системы. То есть, к примеру, на устройстве выбран украинский, по дефолту в приложении английский, а в приложении выбран русский, то в итоге в приложении в выше указанных местах подтягивает украинский контент помимо основного русского.

Пробивал обрабатывать в onConfigurationChanged():

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    locale = new Locale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
}
```

и убрал с каждого activity в manifest.xml android:configChanges = "locale".

Не помогло.

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 3):

Проблему будет выявить сложно, ведь локализация может быть реализована различными путями на девайсах от разных производителей к примеру.
Я бы пошел другим путем. Для того, чтобы позволить пользователю выбирать язык приложения, я бы создал предзаполненную базу данных, в которой были бы таблицы текстовок со сложным ключем, а именно состоящего из двух ID: 1) Это ID текстовки(фразы); 2) Это ID самого языка. В последствии вы бы в нужном месте знали бы какая фраза должна быть там, знали бы айди этой фразы,а пользователь выбиралбы "ID" языка. Следом по этим 2-м параметрам вы бы могли доставать из базы нужные текстовки. Это будет работать всегда и везде, но при этом прийдется спроектировать небольшую БД и реализовать работу с ней.